# How would you do a clickable calendar in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Has anyone already thought about how to do a clickable calendar in Mathematica? There seems to be something here http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/108/, but I quickly tested it and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you provided seems to work, at least partially.

After loading the notebook from the WR site, scanning, applying all the automatically generated suggestions and evaluating it, the following code:

```
CellPrint[
 Cell[BoxData[
   GridBox[{{ButtonBox["January 2003", 
       Background -> RGBColor[0.4, 0, 0.4], 
       ButtonFunction -> Null]}, {GridBox[
       Prepend[monthlayout[1, 2003] /. 
         i : (_Integer | _String) :> 
          ButtonBox[i, Background -> RGBColor[1, 0.6, 0.8], 
           ButtonFunction -> (FrontEndToken["New"] &)], 
        alldays /. 
         s_String :> 
          ButtonBox[s, Background -> RGBColor[0.8, 0.2, 0.6], 
           ButtonFunction -> Null]]]}}]], "Output"]]
```

displays a clickable calendar that opens a new notebook when you click on any day button

[image]

Comment: @Mr. I thought the first two sentences in my answer were clear enough. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Mr. I see. Your reading is plausible. I have edited my answer, hopefully avoiding it.

Comment: OK thanks, it works by me also, it didn't work because I tried from the browser plugin.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly more elaborate example:

http://dev.ragfield.com/2009/03/flickcalendar.html

Comment: Usually, answers that depends entirely on external links are frowned upon here. Can you post here the substantial bits of your link?